# Spring property representation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, yaml

I am currently working on the spring boot and have one question regarding the spring properties representation.

Let say, if I am `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.healthCheckUrl`, the autocomplete inside the `IntelliJ` show healthCheckUrl as `health-Check-Url`. However, if inside the ConsulDiscoveryProperties, the variable is healthCheckUrl.

So, I just want to make sure what causes this difference? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: All the [common-application-properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) are independent of any IDE.**

So, if it is `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.healthCheckUrl` it will always be the same. The Intellisense may not be working properly.